# read receipt feature with firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to change the value of `seen` of every message in my database when a user opens the `ChatActivity` . This is my database structure

[image]

I don't know the right place to do this either when the message is been loaded in `ChatActivity` or in the message adapter.

This is the `MessageAdapter`

```
void bind(Messages message) {

            String user_id = message.getFrom();
            String message_type = message.getType();

            //  what is the right value to get for this task
            String seen = message.getKey();  // this or 

            boolean seen2 = message.isSeen(); // this


            if (message_type.equals("text")) {


                messageText.setText(message.getMessage());
                timeText.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(message.getTime()));
                mSentImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else {
                messageText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Picasso.with(mSentImage.getContext()).load(message.getMessage()).into(mSentImage);
```

Comment: Both could work, and I don't think there is a real right or wrong here. What's your concern? If you have no concern, I'd implement one and see how it works for your use-case.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen any method would be fine, i just want to get it done by any means